# What are the packages the average user will want to install?

Tags: software-recommendation, community

I have heard the users asking for Media Player and GIMP. Are there any other packages I should install on a new PC?

My users are not very technical (school teachers and staff).

Comment: One of the purposes of Debian's design for apt-based package management is to keep software small and compatible, so it can be installed rapidly on-demand by non-experts instead of at install-time by experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the homework yourself & look at what is the most popular (ie. popcon results (*popularity contest*); ie. list the the most popular packages for Ubuntu and fact as your guide

https://popcon.ubuntu.com/

Yes it rates by package (of which Gimp is 666th highest ranked) and may require a little effort to actually get the '*seed from the chaff*' - but it's an actual answer and not just opinion.

`popcon` results include

> Format
>
> - *name* is the package name;
> - *inst* is the number of people who installed this package;
> - *vote* is the number of people who use this package regularly;
> - *old* is the number of people who installed, but don't use this package regularly;
> - *recent* is the number of people who upgraded this package recently;
> - *no-files* is the number of people whose entry didn't contain enough information (atime and ctime were 0).